# $(E,\mathcal{E})$, $(F,\mathcal{F}) = (R,\mathcal{B})$: $ I_{A}$ on $E$ is measurable if and only if A $\in \mathcal{E}$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have this Theorem from the book Probability Essentials written by Jacod and Protter. I do not understand the proof and it would be really helpful if you could give me some insights why this actually proof the stated theorem.

Statement:
Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ and $(F,\mathcal{F}) = (R,\mathcal{B})$ be measurbale spaces. Then an indicator function $I_{A}$ on $E$ is measurable if and only if A $\in \mathcal{E}$.

Proof: If $B \subset R$ then

$
(I_{A})^{-1}(B)=\begin{cases}\emptyset &\text{if 1 $\notin$ B and 0 $\notin$ B}\\A&\text{if 1 $\in$ B and 0 $\notin$ B}\\A^{c}&\text{if 1 $\notin$ B and 0 $\in$ B}\\E&\text{if 1 $\in$ B and 0 $\in$ B}\end{cases}
$

The result follows.

Ok and now I don't get why the result should follow. To show that a function $X:(E,\mathcal{E}) \to (R,\mathcal{B})$is measurable I have to show that for $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{B}$, where $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$, $X^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal{E}$ for all $C \in \mathcal{C}$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel Algebra I can pick any open intervall on $R$, hence $B \subset R$. Then the case division of $(I_{A})^{-1}(B)$ is pretty straight forward, however, I dont see why this leads to the statement. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: If $A$ is measurable set, clearly $I_A$ is measurable by identification of $I_A^{-1}(B)$ (for any borel set $B$ preimage can only be one of $\emptyset,A,A^{c},E$ which are all measurable). On the other hand, if $I_A$ is measurable, then all of preimages of borel sets must be measurable in $E$, and considering  preimages of borel set $\{1\}$, $A$ is measurable.

Comment: Your definition for measurability of functions is correct: just take $\mathcal{C}= \mathcal{B}$. Then take any set $B \in \mathcal{C}$. 
Then the preimage of $B$ under the function $I_A$ can only be one of the four cases above, all of which are in $\mathcal{E}$ if and only if $A \in \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: @Cett so I take $B \in \mathcal{B}$  where $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{C}$. But could I also take $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{B}$ and  $B \in \mathcal{C}$? Since it is confusing for me that I take  $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{C}$ - I would not need this definition of measurability of functions then since I thought this deifnition makes it more convenient to check measurbility since I only need to check the condition for the preimages for a small subset?

Comment: @Methamortix, yes in general it is very usefull to check only a smaller subset, but in this case this not really necesarry, since your function is very simple.

Comment: Ok Thanks this was really the part that confused me a lot but now it is clearer. thank you a lot :)